# Is there any API to retrieve data from Popularity Trends in Sharepoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, popularity-trends

I'm using SharePoint Server 2016 and as we know there is a feature called "Popularity Trends" which gives a report on number of hits and unique users with the graphs for the library.

So, instead of downloading the report every time, I have to show that numbers and graphs directly in a custom website.

Is there any API or any solution to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such API per my knowledge could be used to download Popularity Trends report.